# Why is this angle incorrect for AC current I_norton?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I cannot seem to get the correct angle. I've done this problem multiple times and still get -75 degrees.

All I do is 162cos(200t - 30) ->

convert to phasor domain (162cos(-30) + 162i*sin(-30)) = Vs

To get I_norton, I divide this result by the impedance of the resistor and inductor (10 + 50 * 10^(-3) * j * 200). Right? Why is this not yielding the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Treat this like a voltage divider:
Now,

\$ R = 10 \Omega \$

\$ X_L = j \omega L = j200 \cdot 50 \cdot 10^{-3} = j10 .\Omega \$

\$ X_C = {{-j} \over { \omega C} } = {{-j} \over {200 \cdot 500 \cdot 10^{-6}} } = {{-j} \over {10^{-1}} } = -j10 . \Omega \$

\$ V_{ab} = V_C = V_{Thevenin} = V_T , \$

\begin{eqnarray*}
 V_T &=& V_S ∙{{X_C} \over {R + X_L + X_C}}\\
&=& 162 ∠ 60^∘ \cdot {{-j10} \over {10 + j10 + -j10}}\\
&=& 162 ∠ 60^∘ \cdot {{-j10} \over {10}}\\
&=& -j \cdot 162 ∠ 60^∘ \\
&=& 162 ∠ 60^∘ \cdot 1 ∠ {-90}^∘\\
&=& 162 ∠ (60^∘ - 90^∘)\\
&=& 162 ∠ {-30^∘} . V\\
\end{eqnarray*}

\$ Z_N = Z_{Norton} = Z_{Thevenin}  = Z_T \$ is the impedance looking into the terminals ab, and shorting any voltage sources, and opening any current sources.

So,

\begin{eqnarray*}
Z_N = Z_T &=& {X_C \parallel ({R + X_L}) }\\
&=& {-j10} \parallel (10 + j10)\\
&=& \lbrace (-j10)^{-1} + (10+j10)^{-1} \rbrace ^{-1} \\
&=& \lbrace{ {10}\over {100 - j100} }\rbrace   ^{-1}  \\
&=& 10 - j10 . Ω\\
&=& 10√2 ∠ {-45^∘}.Ω \\
\end{eqnarray*}

So,

\$ I_N = {{V_T} \over {Z_N}} = 11.46 ∠ 15^∘.A \space   \blacksquare   \$

Comment: V thevenin is not equal to Vs

Comment: This answer is right. The norton current is the short circuit current of the thevenin equivalent (actually the last step in the answer), which is Vthevenin series with the norton/thevenin impedance.

Comment: No, this is wrong. V thevenin is not equal to Vs. My answer, was correct. There was a problem in the textbook after talking to my professor

Comment: Oh my bad, I think I understand now. Your polar coordinate indicates sin. I had assumed it indicated cos. sorry about that